# mysql: grouping rows with same txn ids

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, a transactions table, and transactions_items table:

**transactions:**

```
ID Customer Amt
1  Bill     500
2  Helen    100
```

**transactions_items:**

```
ID Code Price
1  R2   100
1  R3   200
1  R5   100
2  R5   100
```

**I want to group them as such:**

```
ID Customer Code Price Amt
1  Bill     R2   100   500
            R3   200   
            R5   100
2  Helen    R5   100   100
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can possibly do that but you have tons of work to do, do it in your application level, you will be needing this query,

```
SELECT  a.*, 
        b.code,
        b.price,
        c.amt
FROM    transaction a
        INNER JOIN transaction_items b
            ON a.ID = b.ID
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT ID, SUM(Price) Amt
            FROM transactions_Items
            GROUP BY ID
        ) c ON a.ID = c.ID
ORDER BY b.code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get by this

```
select transactions.id,transactions.customer,transaction_items.code,transaction_items.price,transactions.amount 
from transactions  
left outer join 
transaction_items  on a.id=b.id;
```